# Opening jar file in C# not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, jar, process, executable-jar

My Jar file is OK and working properly when double click on it, then I make a new .exe launcher in C# which contains one icon and launch method but its not working. I have tried 2 methods but both fails.

**Method 1**

```
 using (Process mp = new Process())
            {
                mp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                mp.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
                mp.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar D:\\isg\\iSearchGurbani.jar";
                mp.Start();
            }
```

**Method 2**

```
   Process.Start("D:\\isg\\iSearchGurbani.jar");
```

First of all it displays an error dialog box and then blank jar file opens....

Error Message Image :
      [image: ErrorMsg]

And the blank jar file :

[image: Blank Jar file]

Comment: Something clearly confuses your Java program. I have not really a concrete idea, but perhaps try setting the working directory of the process you start to either the location of the java.exe or the location of your Jar file (`mp.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ....`)

Comment: Working directory works.... I have copied my exe launcher to the same directory where jar file exist then it start normally....